# KOHANA 3 ORM: How to use sha1 in ->where

Tags: sha1, kohana-orm

I'd like to make select this way
select from post where sha1(id)=$id;

So I thought this could be in KO3 ORM somethink like:
post = ORM::factory('post')->where('sha1(id)','=',$id)->find();

question is how to use 'sha1(id)' in where function because this way doen't work in KO3-ORM

thnkx

Answer (score 0):

You're just slightly off. It should be:

```
ORM::factory('post')->where('sha1("id")','=',$id)->find();
```